# No module named 'cv2' - tried to solve with existing answers

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

So basically I am using PyCharm with Anaconda env Python 3.6. I tried reinstalling everything, folder with my projects env contains the whole package for opencv, in Anaconda Navigator also and PyCharm recognises cv2 when I import (code) yet when i start my main.py it says that there is no cv2 module.
Anyone any ideas why the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first thing you should check is if your conda environment is configured to your project when you're using PyCharm. Have a look at this: [https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#:~:text=Configuring%20a%20conda%20environment%20in%20PyCharm,-In%20the%20Settings&text=Select%20Preferences.,dialog%20box%2C%20select%20Conda%20Environment](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#:%7E:text=Configuring%20a%20conda%20environment%20in%20PyCharm,-In%20the%20Settings&text=Select%20Preferences.,dialog%20box%2C%20select%20Conda%20Environment).